# Django ModelForm returns None instead of HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I've been following the tutorial for 'File Upload With Model Forms' here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

I'm pretty sure I followed it to the letter (except using my own project). However I'm getting the error

`The view myproject.views.InspectionReportForm_Create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class Inspection(models.Model):
InspectionID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
PartID = models.ForeignKey('Part', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

@classmethod
def create(cls, partid):
    inspection = cls(PartID = partid)
    return inspection

class InspectionReport(models.Model):
    ReportID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    InspectionID = models.ForeignKey('Inspection', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    Comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    FileName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    Report = models.FileField(upload_to='docs', null=True, blank=True)
    Signature = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, inspid, date, comment, rept, sig):
        inspreport = cls(InspectionID = inspid, Date = date, Comment = comment, Report = rept, Signature = sig)
        return inspreport
```

forms.py:

```
class InspectionReportForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = InspectionReport
    fields = ('InspectionID', 'Date', 'Comment', 'Report', 'Signature')
```

views.py:

```
def InspectionReportForm_Create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InspectionReportForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('sites/1')
        else:
            form = InspectionReportForm()
        return render(request, 'moorings/uploadReport.html', {'form': form })
```

uploadReport.html (just the form. everything else is styling and titles etc):

```
<div id="wrapper" class="dark">


        <div id="loginwrapper" class="dark">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Create</button>

            </form>

        </div>

</div>
```

The misfitting div name on the form wrapper is just because I reused the layout from my login page which used a similar form.

EDIT: One thing that might be the issue... the tutorial doesn't say anything about urls.py. So I added this in, which may or may not be correct:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('sites/<int:site>', views.sites, name='sites'),
path('parts/<int:part>', views.parts, name='parts'),
path('signup/', views.signup, name = 'signup'),
path('uploadReport/', views.InspectionReportForm_Create, name = 'CreateReport')
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Your is not valid python syntax. This cannot run. Please update your code and make sure the indentation is exactly the same as in your actual running code. Especially the view function.

Comment: Apologies. That was just a copy paste error on posting the question

Comment: The view function will return `None` if you don't hit an explicit return. The first time you load the view, you will use a GET request, and your code only handles `POST`.  The django docs has examples of how to write a form handling view function.

Comment: I've been confused about that. The tutorial seems to work for others as is. But since I'm new to ModelForms I never really thought too hard on it. Do you know how I would get my intended result here?

Comment: Seems that your `else` clause belongs to the first `if`. Try to dedent the else and the final return statement one level.

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you! That did the trick

Comment: this is not how you redirect. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: @arjun My code here works as I want it to work. I've read through that link but I don't understand your point. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
def InspectionReportForm_Create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InspectionReportForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('sites/1')
        else:
            form = InspectionReportForm()
        return render(request, 'moorings/uploadReport.html', {'form': form })
```

to

```
def InspectionReportForm_Create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InspectionReportForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('sites/1')
    else:
        form = InspectionReportForm()
    return render(request, 'moorings/uploadReport.html', {'form': form })
```